# AWS S3 Serializing Policy Document

Tags: c#, serialization, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm pulling my hair out trying to serialize a policy document so I can start using Amazon Web Services S3 storage.

http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434 describes the following format for the policy document:

```
{"expiration": "2009-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  "conditions": [ 
    {"bucket": "s3-bucket"}, 
    ["starts-with", "$key", "uploads/"],
    {"acl": "private"},
    {"success_action_redirect": "http://localhost/"},
    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""],
    ["content-length-range", 0, 1048576]
  ]
}
```

How can I serialize this in C#? I've tried creating a generic class like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class S3PolicyDocument
{
    [DataMember(Name = "expiration")]
    public DateTime expiration { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "conditions")]
    public List<object> conditions { get; set; }

    public S3PolicyDocument()
    {
        conditions = new List<object>();
    }
}
```

and then populating it like this:

```
S3PolicyDocument policyDoc = new S3PolicyDocument();
policyDoc.expiration = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
S3Bucket bucket = new S3Bucket();
bucket.bucket = "followThru";
S3acl acl = new S3acl();
acl.acl = "private";
S3success_action_redirect sar = new S3success_action_redirect();
sar.success_action_redirect = "";

policyDoc.conditions.Add(bucket);
policyDoc.conditions.Add(new string[] { "starts-with", "$key", "uploads/" });
policyDoc.conditions.Add(acl);
policyDoc.conditions.Add(sar);
policyDoc.conditions.Add(new string[] { "starts-with", "$Content-Type", "" });
```

However I can't serialize this using the `DataContractJsonSerializer`. How do I build this in C#?

Alternatively just pasting that as a constant string, I can't format it properly... If that's the solution, how would I paste it as a string without putting everything on a single line... IE This does not work:

```
string PolicyDoc = "{
  \"expiration\": \"" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\",
  \"conditions\": [ 
    {\"bucket\": \"s3-bucket\"}, 
    [\"starts-with\", \"$key\", \"uploads/\"],
    {\"acl\": \"private\"},
    {\"success_action_redirect\": \"http://baasdf/\"},
    [\"starts-with\", \"$Content-Type\", \"\"],
    [\"content-length-range\", 0, 1048576]
  ]
}";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the values can all be formatted as arrays. So changing the class to below will work.

```
[DataContract]
public class S3PolicyDocument
{
    [DataMember(Name = "expiration")]
    public string expiration { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "conditions")]
    public List<string[]> conditions { get; set; }

    public S3PolicyDocument()
    {
        conditions = new List<string[]>();
    }
}
```

Populate the class like so:

```
S3PolicyDocument policyDoc = new S3PolicyDocument();
policyDoc.expiration = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff'Z'");
policyDoc.conditions.Add(new string[] { "eq", "$bucket", "apples" });
policyDoc.conditions.Add(new string[] { "starts-with", "$key", "uploads/" });
policyDoc.conditions.Add(new string[] { "starts-with", "$acl", "private" });
policyDoc.conditions.Add(new string[] { "starts-with", "$success_action_redirect", "" });
```